# Brasero asking me to create an image

Tags: brasero

I want to burn some data onto a CD.

I have added the folder I want to burn to the project and inserted a blank CD. However, when I press "Burn.." I am asked to chose a location to  create the image file "brasero.iso". I don't understand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a writable blank CD in the drive? It will ask you that when you don't have a cd. It could also be that your data is larger than a blank CD and need a DVD.

Comment: Oops, I just realised the drive on this computer might not be able to write at all :/ How do I check? I am new to ubuntu.

Comment: Well that could be the reason. :-) I usually just look at the physical drive itself. They usually say on the tray. I'm sure there is a better way, but another way is to check dmesg. Open up a terminal and enter the following command: `dmesg | grep sr0` Here is the output when I do it on my machine:`dmesg | grep sr0
[    1.322486] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.322738] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
`
See, it says that it is a writer.

Comment: I see. Mine does not say writer, so that's why. Thanks :)